# Why does solid pressure depend on area while liquid pressure doesnt

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

I don't understand why solid pressure depends on.surface area while liquid pressure doesn't , liquid have weight and if a container is v shaped then all the weight above is acting on small base area of container similar to the pressure of container on the table the whole weight of container is acting on a small area then pressure will increase . I know pressure of liquids doesn't depend on area but how and why it doesn't while solids depend what is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

The pressure due to a fluid, as you may know, is often written as $P=\rho g h$ where $h$ is the depth of the point where we are measuring the pressure, $g$ is the gravitational acceleration and $\rho$ is the density of the solid. We can simply convert the dependence on density to dependence on area by multiplying and dividing by area. Therefore,

$$P=\rho g h \frac A A =g\frac{\rho h A}{A}= g \frac{M}{A}=\frac{Mg}{A} \tag{1}$$

Here $A$ is the cross section area of the container and $M$ is the mass of the liquid above our surface of pressure measurement. But $(1)$ is exactly the expression of pressure exerted on a surface by a solid of mass $M$ and of cross section area $A$.

We can also go the other way around. The pressure exerted by a solid of mass $M$ and cross sectional area $A$ is $P=Mg/A$. Now we can write the mass of the solid $M$ as,

$$M=\rho_\mathrm s V=\rho_\mathrm s A h$$

where $\rho_\mathrm s$ is the density of the solid, $V$ is the volume of the solid and $h$ is the height of the solid. Substituting this $M$ into the pressure equation for solid, we get

$$P=\frac{(\rho_\mathrm s A h)g}{A}=\rho_s g h \tag{2}$$

But this is exactly the expression of pressure for a fluid. Thus from $(1)$ and $(2)$, we can say that

$$\rho g h \equiv \frac{Mg}{A}$$

The expression of pressure due to a fluid and due to a solid are both equivalent. It is just because of our convenience that we express the pressure due to a fluid in terms of its density and pressure due to a solid in terms of its mass. The above arguments hold true only when the cross sectional area does not change with height.

---

In the case of a V-shaped container, the slanted walls of the container exert a normal force in the upward direction such that the pressure at depth $h$ stays $\rho g h$. This is also quoted as the famous [Pascal's Law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_law). Thus the bottom pressure on the container will stay the same, no matter what the shape of the container is, as long as the depth is the same.

Comment: this answer is wrong, in the sense. that it describes not what was asked, water in a V shaped container, with not uniform A

Comment: @trula Thanks for pointing that out, I had totally missed that. I have updated my answer, please take a look.

Comment: But how this happens as pressure acts in all directions

Comment: @emanahmed Please clarify what you are talking about.

Comment: I mean if pressure acts in all directions then this will make water molecules static then there will be no weight and also I am still confused I still hadn't got it can you please explain it for me again

Answer (score 1):

[image: visualisation on a V shaped container]

Not all the weight of the liquid weights on the bottom g, only the part over g, the rest goes to the walls, if you imagine the V shape in very small steps. liquid pressure goes to all sides, which you can see, if you make a hole at some height, the water pours out , if you stand on a surface and put some of your weight on your hands on a table, the pressure your feet make is less.